# vim : YankRing interfering with 'dt' commands?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm loving YankRing, but I have lost a key shortcut.  Before YankRing, I could delete text to the end of the line with:

```
dt$
```

With YankRing, now when I enter 'dt', I get a prompt for the character I want to delete to.  If I enter '$' it looks for a '$' character in the string, not the end of the line.  Is there a way to unescape $ to it's end-of-line meaning, or suspend YankRing for just this bit?  I tried 'YRToggle' to turn off YankRing, but I get the same behavior.

Any help is appreciated.

ADDED: It might not just be YankRing, as I'm thinking about it.  For reference, here is a pastebin of my whole .vimrc file: http://pastebin.com/EhhK3215

Comment: dt$ doesn't work for me (it does nothing) but if I want to delete everything to the right from the cursor I use D.

Comment: Kimi - that's perfect for me!  If it were a solution (as opposed to a comment here), I would accept it!  I didn't know about 'D', so thanks!

Comment: This is not a YankRing problem. `dt$` is actually supposed to delete from the cursor to the next `$` on the line. To delete from the cursor to the end of the line, that would be `d$` or, like Kimi showed you, `D`.

Comment: Unfortunately YankRing really pollutes the mapping space by default, more so than almost any plugin I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>D</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) is a synonym for <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks!  I think maybe I never had 'dt$' available to me anyway before I added these helper plug-ins... still fairly new, and my memory isn't too reliable.  So thanks again to Kimi and romainl.